# Duplicate files in APK error

Tags: java, android

I am trying to use the Watson java wrapper in my android project. When I just add

```
compile 'com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud:java-wrapper:0.1.4'
```

to my gradle, I am getting Duplicate files found in `META-INF/LICENSE` error. Do anyone know's how to fix this ?

My **build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.cool.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud:java-wrapper:0.1.4'
}
```

**The `Messages Gradle` display me this**

```
Error:duplicate files during packaging of APK /Users/Shaik/Downloads/AskAshiq/app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug-unaligned.apk
    Path in archive: META-INF/DEPENDENCIES
    Origin 1: /Users/Shaik/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.james/apache-mime4j/0.6/945007627e8d12275d755081a9e609c018e1210d/apache-mime4j-0.6.jar
    Origin 2: /Users/Shaik/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpcore/4.0.1/e813b8722c387b22e1adccf7914729db09bcb4a9/httpcore-4.0.1.jar
You can ignore those files in your build.gradle:
    android {
      packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
      }
    }
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug'.
> Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/DEPENDENCIES
    File 1: /Users/Shaik/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.james/apache-mime4j/0.6/945007627e8d12275d755081a9e609c018e1210d/apache-mime4j-0.6.jar
    File 2: /Users/Shaik/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpcore/4.0.1/e813b8722c387b22e1adccf7914729db09bcb4a9/httpcore-4.0.1.jar
```

**Adding this also does not help**

```
  packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to exclude all files by adding.

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
}
```